# Transform an XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to transform an XML using XSLT.
Here is my sample XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <aaa>
      <bbb>
         <ccc>123</ccc>
         <ggg>2010.2</ggg>
      </bbb>
   </aaa>
   <ddd>
      <eee>112</eee>
      <fff>234</fff>
   </ddd>
   <ddd>
      <eee>456</eee>
      <fff>345</fff>
   </ddd>
</root>
```

I'm trying to get below xml using xslt.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <aaa>
      <bbb>
         <ccc>123</ccc>
         <ggg>2010.2</ggg>
         <ddd>
            <eee>112</eee>
            <fff>234</fff>
         </ddd>
         <ddd>
            <eee>456</eee>
            <fff>345</fff>
         </ddd>
      </bbb>
   </aaa>
</root>
```

I tried with below XSLT to get above xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <!-- Identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="aaa[following-sibling::ddd]">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
         <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::ddd" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="ddd" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I'm getting a wrong output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <aaa>
      <bbb>
         <ccc>123</ccc>
         <ggg>2010.2</ggg>
      </bbb>
      <ddd>
         <eee>112</eee>
         <fff>234</fff>
      </ddd>
      <ddd>
         <eee>456</eee>
         <fff>345</fff>
      </ddd>
   </aaa>
</root>
```

Could someone please help me.

Comment: Change the `match="aaa[following-sibling::ddd]"` to `match="aaa[following-sibling::ddd]/bbb"` and then the `<xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::ddd"/>` to `<xsl:copy-of select="parent::aaa/following-sibling::ddd"/>`.

Comment: Thanks Martin, Your suggestion worked. I'll post the complete answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using below XSLT, the required xml can be obtained.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
       <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
          <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
          </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:template>
       <xsl:template match="aaa[following-sibling::ddd]/bbb">
          <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
             <xsl:copy-of select="parent::aaa/following-sibling::ddd" />
          </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:template>
       <xsl:template match="ddd" />
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <!-- Identity transform for everything -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <!-- copy the stuff from bbb -->
   <xsl:template match="aaa[following-sibling::ddd]/bbb">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
         <!-- then include the embedded ddd -->
         <xsl:copy-of select="aaa/following-sibling::ddd" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
  <!-- note the empty template for ddd is gone -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

The changes required were quite small:

- The template shouls match `bbb` (not `aaa`).
- The `foollowing-sibling` predicate should be prepended with `../`.
- The same for `copy-of`.

Below you have a complete script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="bbb[../following-sibling::ddd]">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
         <xsl:copy-of select="../following-sibling::ddd" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="ddd" />

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```